# CefSharp with Proxy Authentication

Tags: c#, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I want to use CefSharp with proxy.

I have the following code in C#:-

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CachePath = "cache";
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", ProxyAddress);

            Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

But I also want to provide proxy username and password.  How can I do proxy authentication in CefSharp ?

Comment: Read the proxy resolution section in the general usage guide. Just Google CefSharp general usage

Comment: @amaitland  Can you show code example using C#

Comment: Search through the source